# Searching for an efficient method to find the interception of multiple lines / the vanishing point of an optical flow analyses

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opticalflow

[image: Optical Flow]

[image: Problem]

Hello,

i have calculated the optical flow (shown in Picture 1). What I want is a "vanishing point" from the optical flow. Looking at picture 2, most of the lines point at a certain area (red circle).

I tried calculating all interceptions and finding the middle of them, but this is far from efficient.

My second try would be to draw all lines in a new picture and find an optical maximum (somewhat similar to the hough-space).
But maybe there is a far more efficient way to do this, that I'm missing out?